# Vectors Problem: Prove that for a random point O, a line segment AB, and a point N such that AN+2NB=0, NO=OA-2AB

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, solution-verification, vectors, proof-explanation

[There were typos in the question. One should actually end up with NO=-OA-2AB]

I was given the following problem by a student I am tutoring. It was given to him as homework. The problem is:

We are given a line segment AB and a point N such that AN+2NB=0. Given a random point O prove that NO=OA-2AB.

No matter what i try, I always end up with NO=-OA-2AB. Am I wrong or the thing that it is asked to be proven is stated wrong / has a typo?

Comment: Neither is right. Assuming signed segments, $AB=AN+NB=\frac{3}{2}AN$, then $NO=NA+AO=\dots$

Comment: nope. doesn't lead to anywhere. Point N does not lie on AB. Also, it's AN+2NB=0. Your way leads nowhere either.

Comment: With the sign correction you'll get $\,AB=\frac{1}{2}AN\,$, then $\,NO=-OA-2AB\,$ (again assuming signed segments). "*Point $N$ does not lie on $AB$*" $\;-\;$ You should clarify what $AN$, $NB$ etc are supposed to mean.

Comment: i know... it was given to me that way, no further clarifications or explanations... it was a mess of an exercise